# Getting Fiddler to capture remote traffic

Tags: c#, asp.net, fiddler

On my webserver I have an web app installed and I want to monitor traffic to/from that app. Hence I installed Fiddler.
When I browse to that app from the webserver/through localhost the traffic is captured however when I browse to the web app from a different server no traffic is captured.

I tried adding:

```
 <system.net>
     <defaultProxy enabled="true">
         <proxy proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="False"/>
     </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

to web.config and to machine.config with no success.

Comment: Fiddler has to be installed at the client side. No wonder if you browse from a different server, nothing is captured.

Comment: It should be possible to just install it on the server side and see client requests to that server and server responses. No?

Comment: This is probably closest to what you could do, however, I am not sure if this solves your case https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorRemoteMachine

Comment: @wiktor-zychla This seems to indeed be the best I can do. Please move your comment to the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer accepted by the OP involves installing Fiddler at the server, checking the *Allow remote computers to connect in options* and setting the proxy at the client that points to the server on the port Fiddler is exposed.

They have some screenshots of this setup [here](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorRemoteMachine).